# working with session on zf2 (recover container)

Tags: session, zend-framework2

### PRECEDENTS:

- using a custom hack OF ZfcUserLdap to authenticate against a LDAP server (include zfcUser too as dependency)
- the hack is due the Ldap server uses a ldapc wrapper, so the bind and search process doesn't belong to Ldap standards but through a ldapc library
- the login/password box works great against the Ldap server by modifying the bind and findbyuser methods

### NEED:

- add country selection at login step
- check if the user has the permission to work with this country (so to have the country here has sense, don't need ACL, it will be check through LDAP user groups)
- store the selected country to use along the whole application

### WORK IN PROGRESS:

- add SELECT dropdown with available countries to login box [OK]
- get the country selected at the login form                [OK]

  -> at authenticate method on ZfcUserLdap\Authentication\Adapter\Ldap.php class I get correctly the country set at the form

### PROBLEM:

- how to store the country into a session variable,

  -> since zfcUser has an Storage defined and the country is defined at the login step, I would like to use that Storage

I will appreciate any kind of clarification or tips to accomplish this task.

### SOLUTION:

The logic is more at zfcUserLdap module, since the auth is against an LDAP Server.
I added to the Entity extended at zfcUserLdap a new property, *country* that is set to the Entity object along the *findByUsername* method.

```
public function findByUsername($username, $country = null)
{
    $pUser = $this->ldap->findByUsername($username);

    if (isObjectNotNull($pUser))
    {
        $this->entity->setDisplayName(getLdapUserFirstName($pUser) . ' ' . getLdapUserLastName($pUser));
        $this->entity->setEmail(getLdapUserMail($pUser));
        $this->entity->setId(getLdapUserUid($pUser));
        $this->entity->setUsername(getLdapUserUid($pUser));
        $this->entity->setLdapcObject($pUser);
        $this->entity->setUserCountry($country);

        return $this->entity;
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

To have the country here will be useful because the authentication process might check if the username has permission to work within that country. I'll need to add that check later.

Like this, the country is part of the entity object, so I can get the country at the same way I was able to get the username.

For now, I have create a View Helper very similar to ZfcUserDisplayName. I just update the get metohd to get the country property.

```
 $countryName = $user->getUserCountry();
```

I plan to create a Controller Plugin to get the country from any Controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZFCUser has an authenticate event that you should leverage for this. IN your Module's main bootstrap:

```
$sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
$zfcAuthEvents = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('ZfcUser\Authentication\Adapter\AdapterChain')->getEventManager();

$zfcAuthEvents->attach( 'authenticate', function( $authEvent ) use( $sm ){
    try
    {
        // use $authEvent->getIdentity() to get country and stick it in a session

        return true;
    }
    catch( \Exception $x )
    {
        // handle it
    }
});
```

How you store in session is up to you, there's 400 ways to skin that cat.

Comment: I added my solution as an edit, btw your explanation has gave me a new field to research in ZF world.